# Position child mesh based on local vectors in Three.js

Tags: math, matrix, 3d, three.js, rotation

I need help positioning mesh to specific points that are given according to local coordinates. I created pink cylinders with height 0.1 to demonstrate my local points of cubes that I want to make touch each other.

Also I want cube2 to be a child of cube1, but that is not a deal breaker for a moment.

Expected result: Cubes are touching with their specific corners and in proper rotation - pink cylinders should be pixel perfect covering each other.

I tried to solve it with:

```
cube2.position.copy(cube_position.clone().add(cube2_position))
cube2.rotation.setFromVector3(cube_rotation.clone().add(cube2_rotation))
```

But that's not working like expected. Should I use some kind of Matrix transform?

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(25, 25, 12);
// setup cubes

var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(6, 6, 6);
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: 0x00fff0
});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

cube.position.set(0.3, 1, -2);
cube.rotation.set(Math.PI / 3, Math.PI / 2, 1)

var geometry2 = new THREE.CubeGeometry(4, 4, 4);
var material2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: 0x0fff00
});
var cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2, material2);
cube.add(cube2);

cube_position = new THREE.Vector3(3, 3, 3)
cube_rotation = new THREE.Vector3(Math.PI / 3, Math.PI / 4, 0)
cube2_position = new THREE.Vector3(2, -2, 2)
cube2_rotation = new THREE.Vector3(Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2, 0)

// visualize points
vmat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: 0xFF00FF,
  opacity: 0.5,
  transparent: true
});
v1 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(1, 1, 0.1, 10), vmat);
cube.add(v1)
v1.position.copy(cube_position)
v1.rotation.setFromVector3(cube_rotation)

v2 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(1, 1, 0.1, 10), vmat);
cube2.add(v2)
v2.position.copy(cube2_position)
v2.rotation.setFromVector3(cube2_rotation)

// BUG: connect cube with cube2 on specified points

cube2.position.copy(cube_position.clone().add(cube2_position))
cube2.rotation.setFromVector3(cube_rotation.clone().add(cube2_rotation))

// setup rest
var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);
pointLight.position.x = 10;
pointLight.position.y = 50;
pointLight.position.z = 130;
scene.add(pointLight)

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0x20252f);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

animate();

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r82/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://yume.human-interactive.org/examples/buffer-geometry/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, Matrix is really powerful to solve rotation problems. I flow two steps to set the `cube2` rotation and position properly.

- Rotation

  The relationship between `cube1`,`cube2`,`v1`,`v2` is:
  [image]
  What we want is `v2` world rotation equals to `v1` opposite world rotation. When two objects have same rotation, they have same rotation matrix(world matrix). We have these formulae:

  ```
  V1opposite.w = V2.w
  V1opposite.l * C1.w = V2.l * C2.l * C1.l
  V1opposite.l = V2.l * C2.l
  C2.l = V1opposite.l * V2.l(-1)
  ```

  Where V1opposite.w means `v1` opposite world matrix, V2.w is `v2` world matrix, C means `cube`, V2.l(-1) means the inverse matrix of `v2` local matrix. now, we can calculate the `cube2` rotation matrix.
- Position

  What we need is making `v1` and `v2` world position same. Here is a graph to show the coordinate space:[image]
  Because `v2` is a child of `cube2`, we need to move `cube2`. In the world space, we should translate the `cube2` a distance from `v2` to `v1`, now we get the `cube2` world position, `cube2` is a child of `cube1`, just apply the inverse matrix of `cube1` to get the `cube2` local position.

Here is a jsfiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/craigli/gjbkdpjz/).

Wish it helps.

**Update**

I wrote a function, you can use it without `v1` and `v2`.

```
//connect obj1 and obj2 on obj1's point1 and obj2's point2.
function connect(obj1,obj2,point1,point2)
{
    var point1World = new THREE.Vector3().copy(point1).applyMatrix4(obj1.matrixWorld);
    var point2World = new THREE.Vector3().copy(point2).applyMatrix4(obj2.matrixWorld);
    var translation = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(point1World,point2World);
    var obj2World = new THREE.Vector3().copy(obj2.getWorldPosition());
    obj2World.add(translation);
    if(obj2.parent !== null)
    {
        var inverseMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().getInverse(obj2.parent.matrixWorld);
        obj2World.applyMatrix4(inverseMatrix);
    }
    obj2.position.copy(obj2World);
}
```

I also add a grandfather cube to contain `cube1` and `cube2`.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gjbkdpjz/1/)

Comment: Well, it kind of helps, v1 and v2 were only created to demonstrate, so they shouldn't be used to solve this. Also I can't use render inbetween calculations. I'm trying to work around that, so I can use Your solution in my App, but seems impossible

Comment: I rendered because I need to update the position of v2 and cube2, I think it's convenient, if u don't want do that, u can make their position apply the transform matrix. Except using, which way do u want to solve it? Any constraint? I can go on helping.

Comment: I implemented Your solution in my actual app, and everything has weird offset when it is grandchild (child of child of first cube). It drives me crazy, I don't know how to implement it properly.

Comment: @Patryk My solution built on v1, v2. I wonder if I can implement it with cube's conner vertex. And I want to know your end goal, Just touch them on the conner?  Some fixed rotation between them?

Comment: It's more complex, and I can't share source code. Basically I'm building a guided version of 3d editor. v1 and v2 demonstrated a connection between two meshes. In that editor You position every element as child of some other elements. You can have infinite amount of generations of children. Also when I applied Your solution, besides positioning only on one generation of children, it made mesh move to global 0,0,0 for split second each time I run that code.

Comment: I will try to make it work when all elements are children of scene.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148656/discussion-between-craig-li-and-patryk).